# Translating polygons over to another image

Tags: python, image, png

I am trying to shift a polygon associated with one image onto another image. the two images are identical except for the bounds, the polygon that I want to translate is a marker for an object on the image, how would I[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I14Nw.png) translate the polygon without it getting rotated? I have tried doing rotations, and shear transformations to get the desired results: an image for reference

```
for dictionary in JSONfile:
list_of_c = dictionary['pixel_coordinates']
#set scale
gp_x =35093
gp_y = 23133
sr_x= 16384
sr_y=16384
t = -215
scales=scale(gp_x,gp_y,sr_x, sr_y)
for item in list_of_c:
    x = item['x']
    y = item['y']
    #1st shear
    new_x = conversion_to_sp(slope,x,y)
    x_1 = new_x
    item['x']= new_x
    item['y']= y
    #2nd rotation

    rotated_coords =rotation_t(t,item['x'],item['y'])
    item['x'] = rotated_coords[0]
    item['y'] = rotated_coords[1]

    #scaling 
    item['x']= rotated_coords[0]*scales[0]
    item['y']= rotated_coords[1]*scales[1]
    #retrun to square hopefully
    x_update= item['x']+slope*item['y']
    item['x']= x_update+18432
    item['y']= item['y']+10240
```

Comment: I don't understand you need the same polyugon in diferent perspectives of image? this would give you a trapezium. or you need a new polygon  containing the same marker? what's your code? what have you tried?

Comment: hello i will update my question to include the code, but there is a rectangle marking an object on the trapezoidal image and i just want to get the coordinates to transform onto the square image while preserving the geometry of the actual marking rectangle, so far i have tried doing affine transforms which only change the shape of the marking geometry . hopefully i can transform the coordinates such that the rectangle marker will stay rectangular and cover the object I want to identify

Comment: @hmm I ithink that's no way that you have a rectangle between points in the second image, cause an affine transformation will generally transform a rectangle into a trapezium. maybe you will have to find the marker in image 2 and set a new rectangle there... the other option is to transform only 2 oposite corners and construct with that the new rectangle (but will differ from the original)

Comment: awesome that is a great starting point, i appreciate the help